# convergence of step functions in $L^1$ norm

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f \in L^1 (m)$. For $k=1,2,3,...$, let $f_k$ be the step function defined by
>    $$
> f_k (x) = k\int_{j/k}^{\frac{j+1}{k}} f(t)dt \  \text{  for  $\frac{j}{k}<x<\frac{j+1}{k}$, $j=0,\pm1,\cdots$.}
> $$
>   Show that $f_k$ converges to $f$ in $L_1$ norm.

This one seems more direct but when I do the $\|f_n - f\|_1$, I have trouble switching the two integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sketch: Changing notation slightly, for $f\in L^1,$ let $S_k(f)$ denote your step function above. Note that the map $f\to S_k(f)$ is linear on $L^1.$ Note also

$$\|S_k(f)\|_1 \le \|f\|_1.$$

Suppose now $g$ is continuous with compact support. Then the result holds for $g$:

$$\|S_k(g) - g\|_1 \to 0.$$

This follows from the uniform continuity of $g$ and the fact that in each subinterval corresponding to $k,$ the average of $f$ over that interval equals $f(c)$ for some $c$ in that interval.

Now fix $f\in L^1$ and let $\epsilon>0.$ Then we can choose $g$ as above with $\|f-g\|_1 < \epsilon.$ So

$$\|S_k(f)-f\|_1 \le \|S_k(f)-S_k(g)\|_1 + \|S_k(g)-g\|_1 + \|g-f\|_1$$ $$ \le \|f-g\|_1 + \|S_k(g)-g\|_1 + \|g-f\|_1 < \epsilon+\|S_k(g)-g\|_1+\epsilon.$$

Let $k\to \infty$ to see the $\limsup \|S_k(f)-f\|_1\le 2\epsilon.$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have the result.

Comment: So $S_k (g)$ is just the translation of $g$?

Comment: No, it's the same step function you defined above, applied to $g.$

Comment: I know. You just mentioned the average of the integral $f(c)$ and I assume $S_k (g)$ should be equal to some $g(c)$.